# Why Caption looks like that

Tags: captions

I'm writting this table:

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\caption{$\sigma(gg\to H \to X X^*)\mbox{fb}$ in $SU(5)_{eff}$ model at $\sin \beta \sim \sin \alpha$, $m_S$= 500 GeV, $Y_4=0.66- 0.69$, $k_i=10$, and $\zeta=-10$.}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
Channel   & $~ \sigma(gg\to H \to X X^*)~ \mbox{fb}~ $ & Exp. upper bound ~ fb  \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
\hline
$WW^*$ & 11 &  54   \\
[1ex]
ZZ & 5 & 12  \\
[1ex]
$t\bar{t}$ & 148    &  550   \\
[1ex]
hh & 4  & 35    \\
[1ex]
jj & 5  & 15    \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}
%
```

The problem is that the Caption is corrupted by spaces like:

[image]

I don't know why this happens, the Captions in the other figures in the TeX file looks fine.

**Edit**

Here is my LaTeX file preamble:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% generic macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\topmargin      -1.cm  % distance to headers
\textwidth       170mm  % Horizontal alignment
\textheight      235mm  % height of text
\def\unit{\leavevmode\hbox{\small1\kern-3.6pt\normalsize1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.12} \normalsize

\def\lsim{\raise0.3ex\hbox{$\;<$\kern-0.75em\raise-1.1ex\hbox{$\sim\;$}}}
\def\gsim{\raise0.3ex\hbox{$\;>$\kern-0.75em\raise-1.1ex\hbox{$\sim\;$}}}
\def\Frac#1#2{\frac{\displaystyle{#1}}{\displaystyle{#2}}}
\def\etal{{\it et al.}}
\def\eg{{\it e.g.}}
\def\ie{{\it i.e.}}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\B}[1]{\ifmmode\bm{#1}\else\textbf{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\x}[2]{#1 \times #2}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{Eq.~(\ref{#1})}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mu_1^2}
\newcommand{\2}{\mu_2^2}
\newcommand{\3}{\mu_3^2}
\newcommand{\4}{\theta}
\newcommand{\5}{M_{_{Z'}}^2}
\newcommand{\g}{g''^2}
\newcommand{\FF}{{\cal F}}
\newcommand{\n}{\nonumber\\}
\newcommand{\nn}{\tilde{\nu}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\displaystyle}
\def\bea{\begin{eqnarray}}
\def\eea{\end{eqnarray}}
%
\usepackage{epsfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, the reason most likely is hidden in your document preamble. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: In particular, please do tell us how wide the text block is.

Comment: When I try your preamble followed by your table and `\end{document}` I do not get the same caption as you have. Try to scale down your example and give a compilable code that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Even with the preamble, the error will not reproduce for me. Just as an experiment, try removing the caption package.

Answer (score 3):

One problem of your given code is that it is not minimal or compilable as presented in your question.  So I stripped it down to have only the relevant parts inside the code.

The second problem is that you call package `caption` with "bad" result.  If you have a look into the log file you will find something like that:

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
...
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: Incompatible package detected (regarding \caption).
(caption)             \caption = macro:->\minipagefootnote@here \ifx \@captype \@undefined \@latex@error {\noexpand \cap
tion outside float}\@ehd \expandafter \@gobble \else \refstepcounter \@captype \expandafter \@firstofone \fi {\@dblarg {
\@caption \@captype }}.


Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
```

**To make it short**: Do not load package `caption` with this class!

With the following shortened MWE

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[%
  onecolumn,
% twocolumn,
  amsmath,amssymb
]{revtex4}

\topmargin      -1.cm  % distance to headers
\textwidth       170mm  % Horizontal alignment
\textheight      235mm  % height of text
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.12} \normalsize

\usepackage{caption} % <================================================

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

Test text. 
\begin{table}%[!t]
\centering
\caption{$\sigma(gg\to H \to X X^*)~\mbox{fb}$ in $SU(5)_{eff}$ model at 
  $\sin \beta \sim \sin \alpha$, $m_S$= 500 GeV, $Y_4=0.66- 0.69$, 
  $k_i=10$, and $\zeta=-10$.}
\label{tab:tab1}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Channel   & $\sigma(gg\to H \to X X^*)~\mbox{fb}$ & Exp. upper bound~fb  \\[0.5ex]
\midrule
$WW^*$     &  11 &  54 \\[1ex]
ZZ         &   5 &  12 \\[1ex]
$t\bar{t}$ & 148 & 550 \\[1ex]
hh         &   4 &  35 \\[1ex]
jj         &   5 &  15 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
Test text2. See table~\ref{tab:tab1}.

\end{document}
```

I get the following resulting pdf (with the shown messages above):

[image: resulting pdf with caption]

You can see that the table caption shows not the spaces you have.

After commenting the call of package `caption` I get the following resulting pdf (without the warning for package `caption`):

[image]

You see the difference?

Please study my changed MWE, I changed a lot of things. At last you called several packages twice (Do not do this!) and left not used commands in the code I deleted too.

At last I added command `\listfiles` as first line to get an list of all used packages **and** version numbers for the compiling of the MWE.  Please compare the following list with the result on your system.  I guess your system is outdated causing the problem you have:

```
 *File List*
 revtex4.cls    2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
 revsymb.sty    2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amsmath.sty    2016/03/10 v2.15b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
     aps.rtx    2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
    10pt.rtx    2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
showframe.sty    2011/02/24 v0.1i showframe (new impl., RN)
 eso-pic.sty    2015/07/21 v2.0g eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/06/17 v0.06h Graphics/color for pdfTeX
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
supp-pdf.mkii
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********

 )
```

BTW: my used system is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.5.24)
```

(first line of log file) ...

Please add relevant informations to your question, for example all differences in used system and package versions ...